# How to save new position for items after draggable and sortable in dnd-kit use useState and Redux React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I have to make: after adding items from the `EditDsrSubWidgets` component that is in `SideBar`, the items are rendered in `DrsTargetComponent` component, outside of `SideBar` (*already done*), then be able to drag and sort them, and save them on a new position in the local state. Then after clicking on the "Save" button, save them in the Redux store. Pressing the "x" remove button from the local state.

Previously it worked when everything was within `SideBar` and was not connected to Redux.

EditDsrSubWidgets

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { useDroppable, DndContext } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { Box, Flex, useToast, Text } from "@chakra-ui/core";
import { restrictToVerticalAxis } from "@dnd-kit/modifiers";
import { SortableContext } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import ClaverButton from '../../../../global/components/helper-components/components/ClaverButton';
import { updateDsr } from '../../../../digital-sales-room/actions/dsr-actions';
import { addDsrDraggableItems, removeDsrDraggableItems } from '../../../../digital-sales-room/actions/dsr-actions';
import DsrSidebarMenuItem from "../components/dsr-sidebar-subwidgets/DsrSidebarMenuItem";

const sidebarMenuData = [
    {   
        id: 1,
        label: "Title Text",
        route: "/title_text",
        content: 'This is a Title Text',
      },
      { 
        id: 2,
        label: "Normal Text",
        route: "/normal_text",
        content: 'This is a Normal Text',
      },
      { 
        id: 3,
        label: "Space",
        route: "/space",
        content: 'This is a Space Text',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        label: "Image",
        route: "/image",
        content: 'This is a Image Text',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        label: "Loom Video",
        route: "/loom_video",
        content: 'This is a Loom Text',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        label: "Video",
        route: "/video",
        content: 'This is a Text',
      },
];

export function generateUniqueId() {
    return `item-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}`;
}

function EditDsrSubWidgets({ 
  dsrId, 
  isOpen, 
  sidebarRef, 
  actions, 
  updateDsrOutcome, 
}) {
    const [droppedItems, setDroppedItems] = useState([]);
    const [clickedItemIds, setClickedItemIds] = useState([]);

    console.log('droppedItems', droppedItems)

    const handleDrop = (event) => {
        const { active, over } = event;
      
        if (active && over) {
          const draggedItemId = active.id;
          const destinationItemId = over.id;
      
          const draggedItem = sidebarMenuData.find((item) => item.id === draggedItemId);
      
          if (draggedItem) {
            // Assign a unique ID to the dragged item
            const uniqueId = generateUniqueId();
            const itemWithId = { ...draggedItem, id: uniqueId };
            
            setDroppedItems([itemWithId]);

            // Prepare the data to be saved in Redux state
            const dataToSaveInRedux = {
              dsrId,
              droppedItems: [itemWithId],
            };

            // Update the Redux state with the new dragged item
            actions.addDsrDraggableItems(dataToSaveInRedux);
      
            // Find the index of the destination item in the current droppedItems state.
            const destinationIndex = droppedItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === destinationItemId);
      
            // If the destination item is not found in the droppedItems state, add the dragged item to the end.
            if (destinationIndex === -1) {
              setDroppedItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, itemWithId]);
            } else {
              // If the destination item is found, insert the dragged item before it.
              setDroppedItems((prevItems) => {
                const newItems = [...prevItems];
                newItems.splice(destinationIndex, 0, itemWithId);
                return newItems;
              });
            }
          }
        }
    };

    const handleSaveDsrProperties = () => {
        const dataToSaveInRedux = {
            dsrId,
            droppedItems,
          };

        actions.addDsrDraggableItems(dataToSaveInRedux)
    };
  
    return (
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        flexWrap="nowrap"
        alignItems="center"
        >
        <Flex w='100%' justify='flex-end' mb='2em'>
            <ClaverButton 
              label='Save' 
              bg='brand.500' 
              color='white' 
              onClick={() => handleSaveDsrProperties()} 
            />
        </Flex>
        <DndContext onDragEnd={handleDrop} modifiers={[restrictToVerticalAxis]}>
          {/* <SortableContext items={sidebarMenuData.map((item) => item.label)}> */}
            <Flex
              ref={sidebarRef}
              minW="19em"
              w="auto"
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              right={isOpen ? "0" : "-10em"}
              boxShadow="md"
              justify="center"
              align="center"
              transition="right 2s ease-in-out"
            >
              {sidebarMenuData.map((item, index) => (
                <DsrSidebarMenuItem key={item.id} item={item} />
              ))}
            </Flex>
          {/* </SortableContext> */}
        </DndContext>
      </Box>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      droppedItems: state.dsrDraggableItems.items,
    };
};
  
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      actions: bindActionCreators(
        {
          addDsrDraggableItems,
          removeDsrDraggableItems,
        },
        dispatch
      ),
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditDsrSubWidgets));
```

DrsTargetComponent

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { 
  useDraggable,
  useDroppable, 
  DndContext, 
  closestCenter, 
  KeyboardSensor, 
  PointerSensor, 
  useSensor, 
  useSensors 
} from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { restrictToVerticalAxis } from "@dnd-kit/modifiers";
import { 
  Box, 
  Flex, 
  CloseButton,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/core";
import { SortableContext,
  useSortable,
  rectSortingStrategy,
} from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { generateUniqueId } from "../EditDsrSubWidgets";
import { addDsrDraggableItems, removeDsrDraggableItems } from "../../../../../digital-sales-room/actions/dsr-actions";

const DrsTargetComponent = ({ droppedItems, setDroppedItems, actions }) => {
  const [droppedItemsOrder, setDroppedItemsOrder] = useState([...droppedItems]);

  console.log('droppedItemsOrder', droppedItemsOrder)
  console.log('droppedItems', [...droppedItems])

  const { setNodeRef, isOver } = useDroppable({
    id: "droppable",
  });

  const containerStyle = {
    border: isOver ? "2px solid #3295EC" : "2px dashed #E2E8F0",
    minHeight: "250px",
    padding: "1em",
    marginBottom: "1em",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "80%",
    cursor: "grab",
  };

  const handleOnDragEnd = (event) => {
    const { over, active } = event;
  
    if (active && over && active.id !== over.id) {
      const updatedItems = [droppedItems.flatMap((droppedItem) => droppedItem.droppedItems.map((item) => item.id))];
      const draggedItemId = active.id;
      const destinationItemId = over.id;
      const draggedItemIndex = updatedItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === draggedItemId);
      const destinationIndex = updatedItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === destinationItemId);
  
      if (draggedItemIndex !== -1 && destinationIndex !== -1) {
        const [draggedItem] = updatedItems.splice(draggedItemIndex, 1);
        const destinationItem = updatedItems[destinationIndex];
  
        // Check if the destination item exists and if it has an ID.
        // If it doesn't have an ID, assign a unique ID to it.
        if (!destinationItem.id) {
          destinationItem.id = generateUniqueId();
        }
  
        updatedItems.splice(destinationIndex, 0, draggedItem);
        setDroppedItems(updatedItems);
        actions.addDsrDraggableItems(updatedItems);
      }
      console.log('updatedItems', updatedItems)
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDroppedItemsOrder([...droppedItems]);
  }, [droppedItems]);
  
  const handleRemoveItem = (parentId, itemId) => {
    const updatedItems = droppedItems.map((droppedItem) => {
      if (droppedItem.id === parentId) {
        return {
          ...droppedItem,
          droppedItems: droppedItem.droppedItems.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId),
        };
      }
      return droppedItem;
    });
  
    setDroppedItems(updatedItems.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      droppedItems: item.droppedItems.map((subItem) => ({
        ...subItem,
        id: generateUniqueId(), // Assign unique IDs after removal
      })),
    })));
    actions.removeDsrDraggableItems(updatedItems)
    console.log('updatedItems', updatedItems)
  };

  return (
    <Flex 
      ref={setNodeRef} 
      style={containerStyle} 
    >
      <DndContext
        onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}
        modifiers={[restrictToVerticalAxis]}
      >
        <SortableContext
          // items={droppedItemsOrder}
          items={droppedItems.flatMap((droppedItem) =>
            droppedItem.droppedItems.map((item) => item.id)
          )}
          strategy={rectSortingStrategy}
        >
          {droppedItems.map((droppedItem) => (
            <DrsSortableItemGroup 
              key={droppedItem.id} 
              droppedItem={droppedItem} 
              onRemove={handleRemoveItem} />
          ))}
        </SortableContext>
          </DndContext>
    </Flex>
  );
};

const DrsSortableItemGroup = ({ droppedItem, onRemove }) => {
  const itemContainerStyle = {
    width: "80%",
    position: "relative",
    marginBottom: "1em",
  };
  
  return (
    <div style={itemContainerStyle}>
      {droppedItem.droppedItems.map((item) => (
        <DrsTargetItem 
          key={item.id} 
          item={item} 
          parentId={droppedItem.id} 
          onRemove={onRemove} 
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const DrsTargetItem = ({ item, onRemove, parentId, isVisible, removeDsrDraggableItems }) => {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging } =
  useSortable({ id: item.id });

  const transformValue = transform
    ? `translateX(${transform.x}px) translateY(${transform.y}px)`
    : "";

  const itemStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: "0.5em 0",
    padding: "0.5em",
    border: "1px solid #E2E8F0",
    borderRadius: "0.5em",
    minWidth: "100%",
    backgroundColor: isDragging ? "#3295EC1A" : "#F7FAFC",
    textAlign: "center",
    cursor: "grab",
    transition: "",
    transform: transformValue,
    pointerEvents: isDragging ? "none" : "auto",
  };

  const removeButtonStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    right: "0.25em",
    transform: "translateY(-50%)",
    cursor: "pointer",
    color: "black",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    padding: "4px",
    zIndex: 9999,
    pointerEvents: isDragging ? "none" : "auto",
  };

  const handleRemoveClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log("handleRemoveClick triggered");
    if (!isDragging) {
      onRemove(item.id);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={itemStyle}
      {...attributes}
      {...listeners}
    >
      <Text color="#3295EC" fontSize="lg">
        {item.label}
      </Text>
      <CloseButton
        size="sm"
        onClick={handleRemoveClick}
        style={removeButtonStyle}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  droppedItems: state.dsrDraggableItems.items,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(
      {
        addDsrDraggableItems,
        removeDsrDraggableItems,
      },
      dispatch
    ),
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DrsTargetComponent));
```

DsrSidebarMenuItem

```
import React from "react";
import { useDraggable } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { Box, Link, Text } from "@chakra-ui/core";
import { SortableContext, useSortable, rectSortingStrategy } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";

const DsrSidebarMenuItem = ({ item }) => {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition, isDragging } = useSortable({ id: item.id });

  const { isDragging: isItemDragging, listeners: itemListeners, setNodeRef: itemSetNodeRef } = useDraggable({
    id: item.id,
  });

  const transformValue = transform ? `translateX(${transform.x}px) translateY(${transform.y}px)` : "";

  const containerStyle = {
    p: "1em",
    marginBottom: "1em",
    borderRadius: "0.5em",
    border: "1px solid #E2E8F0",
    maxWidth: "16em",
    minWidth: "80%",
    cursor: "grab",
    boxShadow: "sm",
    transform: transformValue,
    transition,
    pointerEvents: isDragging || isItemDragging ? "none" : "auto",
    backgroundColor: isDragging ? "#3295EC1A" : "#F7FAFC",
  };

  const linkStyle = {
    textDecoration: "none",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    color: "#3295EC",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  };

  return (
    <Box
      ref={(node) => {
        setNodeRef(node);
        itemSetNodeRef(node);
      }}
      {...containerStyle}
      {...attributes}
      {...listeners}
      {...itemListeners}
    >
      <Link href={item.route} style={linkStyle}>
        <Text color="#3295EC">{item.label}</Text>
      </Link>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default DsrSidebarMenuItem;
```

Reducer

```js
import { ADD_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS, REMOVE_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS } from '../../actions/dsr-actions-types';

const INITIAL_STATE_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS = { items: [] };

export function dsrDraggableReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS, action) {
  console.log('action', action)
    
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS:
      console.log('action', [...state.items, action.payload])

      return  {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, action.payload],
      };

    case REMOVE_DSR_DRAGGABLE_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Earlier it was without Redux and inside `SideBar` and it worked as expected, sortable and save in new position and remove each item, but after relocate to another component and add Redux, it doesn't work.